# Function to add and replace items in observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im trying to write a function that 1. adds an item to an observable array and 2. replaces the item if it already exists in the array

```
self.addNotification = function (name, availability, note) {
    //see if we already have a line for this product
    var matchingItem = self.notifications.indexOf(name);

    if (matchingItem !== undefined) {
        self.notifications.replace(self.notifications()[index(matchingItem)],
            new Notification(self, name, availability, note));
    }
    else {
        self.notifications.push(new Notification(self, name, availability, note));
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Regards Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer:  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jn9hB/)

Hit F12 in Chrome or use FireBug in FireFox to see console log output.

```
var notifications = {
    notifs: [],
    updateNotifications: function(notification) {
        'use strict';

        var matchIndex;

        for (matchIndex = 0; matchIndex < this.notifs.length; matchIndex += 1) {
            if (this.notifs[matchIndex].name === notification.name) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matchIndex < this.notifs.length) {
            this.notifs.splice(matchIndex, 1, notification);
        } else {
            this.notifs.push(notification);
        }
    }
};

notifications.updateNotifications({
    name: 'John',
    available: false,
    note: "Huzzah!"
});
notifications.updateNotifications({
    name: 'Jane',
    available: true,
    note: "Shazam!"
});
notifications.updateNotifications({
    name: 'Jack',
    available: true,
    note: "Bonzai!"
});
notifications.updateNotifications({
    name: 'Jane',
    available: false,
    note: "Redone!"
});
console.log(notifications);​
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Array.prototype.indexOf` never returns `undefined`. Its either `-1` (*not found*) or any number starting with `0` for the array index.

Comment: Okay thanks, I have changed undefined to -1... But it just keeps adding items to the array.